# Riemann Midpoint Sum getting crazy numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm working on a Midpoint Riemann Sum program, and it finds the integral of a randomly generated `function` called `f`.

Here's what wrote:

```
 public static double FindIntegral (double start, double end, function f)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        double stepsize = 1E-2;
        int numSteps = (int)((end - start) / stepsize);
        for (int i = 0; i < numSteps; i++)
        {
            sum += f(start +  (stepsize * (i + 0.5)));
        }
        return sum * stepsize;
    }
```

The function returns numbers that are too low (I have a reliable checking mechanism). 
I put in x^3 for f, and I got the right answer. I tried a couple of more integrable functions and got a good answer. But somehow once I put in `f` it doesn't work.

Comment: One note: when `i = 0`, `f` is evaluated at a point lower than `start`.

Comment: didn't have any affect on anything when I changed it to `i+.5`.

Comment: I think it would be useful to add details on how `f` is randomly generated. The `FindIntegral` code appears to be fine.

Comment: That portion of the code is from a class that implements am interface that I use.  I have no access to its source code.

Comment: Does reducing the step size give closer results to the desired ones? (Maybe the function rapidly change -- i.e. it has high condition number)

Comment: Let's see a graph of the function that is producing bad results. Probably that function is poorly behaved compared to x-cubed.

Comment: Here are some ideas for better approaches:  (1) right now you fix the step size regardless of the range. It would be better to fix the number of steps, and vary the size to match the range.  (2) Once you've done that, run your function with, say, 500 steps on a function. Then 1000 steps on the same function. Then 2000.  Then 4000.   Then 8000.  And so on. Is the result *converging* or *diverging*?  If its not converging then you've got some very ill-behaved function here that will take special handling.

Answer (score 0):

I got the math formula for "Riemann Midpoint Sum" from [here](https://www.ltcconline.net/greenl/courses/116/IntegrationApps/riemann.htm).

My implementation below seems to get the right answer (using the example function on the page).  I used a class because 1) I could make the algorithm work specifying either the step size or the number of rectangles (I preferred the latter) and 2) I didn't see any reason to hard-code either into the algorithm.

As it turns out your code seemed to work just fine (see below); Make sure the code you have here in your question is what you're executing and make sure your expected result is accurate and that you're supplying good inputs (i.e. you don't have `start` and `end` backwards or the wrong `function f` or something).  In other words what you provided in your question looks fine.  Note `double` is approximate in C# (floating point arithmetic, in general) so to compare equality you can't use `==` unless you want exact if you're using unit tests or something.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {           
        function f = x => 50 / (10 + x * x);    

        // 9.41404285216233
        Console.Out.WriteLine(new RiemannMidpointSum(6).FindIntegral(1, 4, f)); 

        // 9.41654853716462
        Console.Out.WriteLine(new RiemannMidpointSum(1E-2).FindIntegral(1, 4, f));

        // 9.41654853716462
        Console.Out.WriteLine(Program.FindIntegral(1, 4, f));   
    }

    // This is your function.
    public static double FindIntegral (double start, double end, function f)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        double stepsize = 1E-2;
        int numSteps = (int)((end - start) / stepsize);
        for (int i = 0; i < numSteps; i++)
        {
            sum += f(start +  (stepsize * (i + 0.5)));
        }
        return sum * stepsize;
    }   
}

public delegate double function(double d);

public class RiemannMidpointSum
{
    private int? _numberOfRectangles;
    private double? _widthPerRectangle;

    public RiemannMidpointSum(int numberOfRectangles)
    {
        // TODO: Handle non-positive input.
        this._numberOfRectangles = numberOfRectangles;
    }

    public RiemannMidpointSum(double widthPerRectangle)
    {
        // TODO: Handle non-positive input.
        this._widthPerRectangle = widthPerRectangle;
    }

    public double FindIntegral(double a, double b, function f)
    {       
        var totalWidth = b - a;
        var widthPerRectangle = this._widthPerRectangle ?? (totalWidth / this._numberOfRectangles.Value);
        var numberOfRectangles = this._numberOfRectangles ?? ((int)Math.Round(totalWidth / this._widthPerRectangle.Value, 0));

        double sum = 0;     
        foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfRectangles))
        {
            var rectangleMidpointX = a + widthPerRectangle * i + widthPerRectangle / 2;         
            var rectangleHeightY = f(rectangleMidpointX);
            var rectangleArea = widthPerRectangle * rectangleHeightY;

            sum += rectangleArea;
        }       

        return sum;
    }
}
```